# Obtener las columnas que forman parte de una tabla PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Necesito obtener el nombre de las columnas que integran una tabla en postgres, para realizar una búsqueda avanzada de acuerdo a la seleccion de columnas que el usuario seleccione.

**Existe alguna consulta para obtener los nombres de las columnas de una tabla en PostgreSQL?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se podría usar la información del esquema para retornar el nombre de las columnas de una tabla especifica, accediendo especificamente a `information_schema.columns` que tiene los nombres de columna de las tablas.

La consulta en cuestion sería:

```
SELECT column_name                  --Seleccionamos el nombre de columna
FROM information_schema.columns     --Desde information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'       --En el esquema que tenemos las tablas en este caso public
AND table_name   = 'tu_tabla'       --El nombre de la tabla especifica de la que deseamos obtener información
```

Comment: Lo interesante es que es un método estándar (o sea debería funcionar en todos los motores SQL que lo implementen).

Answer (score 1):

Sin embargo usar `information_schema.columns` no es la forma **más óptima** si trabajas en Postgresql, puesto que es más lenta. Ver por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22420).

He aquí otra posibilidad, usando **[`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html)**, es más rápida y completa. En el enlace se puede ver toda la información que puedes obtener con ella.

He aquí un ejemplo de alguna información interesante de nuestra tabla:

<kbd>[**VER DEMO**](http://rextester.com/SNKE42569)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE account(
 user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 username VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 email VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 last_login TIMESTAMP
);


SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.attnum as no,
    a.attname as nombre_columna,
    format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as tipo,
    a.attnotnull as notnull, 
    com.description as descripcion,
    coalesce(i.indisprimary,false) as llave_primaria,
    def.adsrc as default
FROM pg_attribute a 
JOIN pg_class pgc ON pgc.oid = a.attrelid
LEFT JOIN pg_index i ON 
    (pgc.oid = i.indrelid AND i.indkey[0] = a.attnum)
LEFT JOIN pg_description com on 
    (pgc.oid = com.objoid AND a.attnum = com.objsubid)
LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef def ON 
    (a.attrelid = def.adrelid AND a.attnum = def.adnum)
WHERE a.attnum > 0 AND pgc.oid = a.attrelid
AND pg_table_is_visible(pgc.oid)
AND NOT a.attisdropped
 AND pgc.relname = 'account'  -- Nombre de la tabla
ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

**resultado**

```
    no  nombre_columna  tipo                             notnull   descripcion  llave_primaria  default
1   1   user_id         integer                          True      NULL         True            nextval('account_user_id_seq'::regclass)
2   2   username        character varying(50)            True      NULL         False           NULL
3   3   password        character varying(50)            True      NULL         False           NULL
4   4   email           character varying(355)           True      NULL         False           NULL
5   5   created_on      timestamp without time zone      True      NULL         False           NULL
6   6   last_login      timestamp without time zone      False     NULL         False           NULL
```